# How do I selectively override functions of a class

Tags: java, class, interface

I have an abstract class A which contains two functions, both implemented

```
public void entry(){}
public void exit(){}
```

These are internally making system calls which I want to avoid during certain circumstances. I'm a writing a test (separate class) from where I will be making my own calls but I don't want to interfere the normal functioning of the code. What are the ways in which I can achieve this?

One way I was thinking of was to create an interface B with these two functions and creating a class C inside the abstract class implementing this interface and containing the actual code. Inside the abstract class, I would have a function to set the interface instantiation that I want to use. example:

```
public static void setMockProvider(B provider) {
    if (provider != null) {
        mockProvider = provider;
    } else {
        mockProvider = new C();
    }
}
```

And then wherever the entry and exit functions are called, I would do a mockProvider.entry() and mockProvider.exit()

Comment: Use a mock or a spy?

Comment: Why don't you just use a child class of A?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest just like you said. Make an interface with these two methods. and override them where you want different implementations of them.

interface

```
public interface Interface
{
void methodA();
}
```

class A (abstract class)

```
public class A : Interface
{


    void methodDescision(T parameter)
    {
        if(parameter != null)
        {
            methodA();

        }else{
            var YourInnerClass YIC = new YourInnerClass();
            YIC.methodA();
        }

    }

    @Override 
    methodA(){
        // do default stuff
    }

public class YourInnerClass
{
    @Override
    methodA(){
         //do user defined stuff
    }
}

}
```

class B (other class)

```
public class B : Interface
{

    @Override 
    void methodA()
    {
        //your new implementation of that method
    }

}
```

Make sure you implement your interfaces in both classes.

Hope this helps.

cheers!

Comment: But in the normal code flow A.methodA() is called which I cannot change. What I want is when A.methodA() is called, it should check for some parameter and either call the default implementation or a user defined one

Comment: why not make another method whitch takes a parameter? in the interface.than override that in your code. and check if that parameter is null. if it is. run your standard A.methodA() and if its not null do the user defined one. so you're gonna have 3 methods. one that is always called and checks for the parameter. And on its turn executes the methods in your abstract class A

Comment: i edited my code it might work like that but im not entirely sure.
You mentioned you had an inner class aswell so i put that in. 
You can override that method in any class that implements that interface.
All you have to do than is make an instance in the desider method to access your overridden method

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if I fully understand the question but you want to make your own calls without interfering with how the base of the methods work (I'm assuming they are being inherited)?

If so you can do a super() call, the super will call the method of the class you inherited from.

```
@Override
public void entry() {
  super();
  //Your code
}
```